# Modify query to return data from this year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which counts policy by `tarifa`.

```
select substr(tarifa,1,2), count(*)
from   pol p, uvod u, doppov d
where (datum_dop >='1-jan-12')  AND (datum_dop<='31-dec-12')
and izdavanje>='01-jul-07'
and p.orgjed = u.sorgz (+)
and DATUM_PREKIDA is not null
and p.polica=d.polica and d.pov_dopl='P'
and d.status='F'
and cisti_ao(p.polica)!=0 
group by substr(tarifa,1,2)
```

Now I have to modify this query to return only for the current year.

I tried to use the `extract' function but it doesn't work as I expected. How can I limit the data returned to the current year?

**UPDATE**

This is what I try so far:

```
select substr(tarifa,1,2), count(*)
from   pol p, uvod u, doppov d
where  EXTRACT( YEAR FROM datum_dop) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate) 
and izdavanje>='01-jul-07'
and p.orgjed = u.sorgz (+)
and DATUM_PREKIDA is not null
and p.polica=d.polica and d.pov_dopl='P'
and d.status='F'
and cisti_ao(p.polica)!=0 
group by substr(tarifa,1,2)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: You must use `extract (year from datum_dop)` --> which will return the year portion of the provided date and then you can compare it with any constant. to find current year --> `extract (year from sysdate)`

Comment: I updated my question. Look  at UPDATE part

Comment: Still using outdated and obsolete implicit comma syntax and `(+)` operator for joins? Get rid of them and switch to  ANSI-92 explicit  `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: This is old version of Oracle ( I belive  version 8) and I have problem when I use join because It doesnt return what I expect, that's why I use (+) sign

Comment: This: `where  EXTRACT( YEAR FROM datum_dop) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate) ` looks OK, **if** `datum_dop`'s datatype is DATE. If not, it should be, as now you have to convert it to a valid date, and then apply `extract` to it.

Comment: and izdavanje>='01-jul-07' this part confuse me. 
When I try to extract year from this I get error

Comment: @robby o_0 oracle 8i is 21 years old!

Comment: @CaiusJard Something like that I use currently :)
PL/SQL Version 8.0.5.1.0 (Production)
Forms [32 Bit] Version 6.0.5.0.2 (Production)
Oracle Toolkit Version 6.0.5.6.0 (Production)

Comment: @Robby so is your problem fixed? You said "this is what I used" but i'm not sure if it means you have it working now

Comment: I fix it right now :) I found mistake :) 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this will work:

```
where  EXTRACT( YEAR FROM datum_dop) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)
```

it will prevent an index on `datum_pop` being considered - though it might not be used anyway if you're accessing a significant proportion of your data. Even so, another approach is to use a range:

```
where  datum_dop >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'YYYY') 
and    datum_pop < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 12)
```

The `TRUNC(sysdate, 'YYYY')` gives you midnight on the first day of the current year; `ADD_MONTHS(..., 12)` gives you midnight on the first day of next year.

You might not even need the second condition - it depends if `datum_pop` can have dates in the future, i.e. beyond `sysdate`.

---

Not directly related but

```
and izdavanje>='01-jul-07'
```

might work for you in your current session but it relies on implicit conversion of the string value to a date, and another user with different NLS settings might see wrong results or an error. You could use explicit conversion:

```
and izdavanje>=TO_DATE('01-jul-07', 'DD-Mon-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
```

or with a format that doesn't rely on the language::

```
and izdavanje>=TO_DATE('2007-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

or with a date literal (if 8i supports those):

```
and izdavanje>=DATE '2007-07-01'
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation and answer :)